# Problem with xelatex and the \drop command

Tags: xetex, titles

I have the following definition for my title page:

```
%----- TITLE PAGE -----%  
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\raisebox{+1.25ex}{\includegraphics[height=1in]{logo}} } % Generic publisher logo  
\newcommand*{\titleAT}{  
\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document  
\newlength{\drop} % Command for generating a specific amount of whitespace
\drop=0.1\textheight % Define the command as 10% of the total text height  
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par % Thick horizontal line
\vspace{3pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip} % Whitespace between lines
%\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par % Thin horizontal line  
\vspace{0.75\drop} % Whitespace between the top lines and title
\centering % Center all text  
\textcolor{Blue}{  
{\Huge Title of the document}\\[0.5\baselineskip]} % Title line 1
%{\Large OF}\\[0.75\baselineskip] % Title line 2
%{\Huge \LaTeX ~Templates}} % Title line 3

\vspace{0.5\drop} % Whitespace between the title and short horizontal line
\rule{0.4\textwidth}{1.25pt}\par % Short horizontal line under the title
\vspace{\drop} % Whitespace between the thin horizontal line and the author name

{\LARGE \textsc{First Author nanme \\ \ \\ Second Author name }}\par % Author name

\vfill % Whitespace between the author name and publisher text
{\large \textcolor{blue}{\plogo}}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Publisher logo
{\Large \textsc{ Publisher} } }\par % Publisher

\vspace{\drop} % Whitespace under the publisher text

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par % Thin horizontal line
\vspace{2pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip} % Whitespace between lines
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par % Thick horizontal line

\endgroup}

%---- END TITLE PAGE ----%
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
<argument> \drop
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add information about the class you're using and make this into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Please always post complete documents but

```
\newcommand*{\titleAT}{  
\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document  
\newlength{\drop}
```

should be

```
\newlength{\drop}

\newcommand*{\titleAT}{%  
\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
```

Register allocations should be at the top level not inside a group. Whether that is enough to solve the problem it is not possible to say without an example file to test.